# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Web.Services.Package[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2013

Full error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Web.Services.Package[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web.Services.Package'.
```

Getting this error. Stack trace is below. Anyone any idea? Can't seem to get it to go away. It's something to do with a dictionary and passing in `Web.Services.Package[]`, but what does the `[]` mean?

It's one a Razor page, in C#, where I am trying to edit an object of type "Package".

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Web.Services.Package[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web.Services.Package'.]
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +378
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary.set_Model(Object value) +47
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +612
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1..ctor(ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary) +37
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +98
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.set_ViewData(ViewDataDictionary value) +39
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +425
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what's wrong you're passing an array vs a string `'Web.Services.Package[]'` is not the same as `'Web.Services.Package'` [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)

Comment: You are passing collection while your view expects single object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` means an [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which means a series of objects of the given type. There are some specifics as to how this works in-memory, but these specifics only serve to differentiate it from other collection types.

In this case, you need to figure out why you're trying to pass *multiple* packages, and you might have to simply pass the first element instead via `array[0]` where `array` is the name of the variable being reported as an array type.